# PARSE ERROR: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Как всегда накалываюсь на эти скобки в выводе.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

```
<?echo "<a href=\"."$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]\"."$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]>."</a>";?>
```

Comment: Точки-кавычки местами не путайте)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Плюсануть не могу, не хватает очков уважения) Но очень благодарен, я постоянно в этом месте затыкаюсь когда доходит до точек-кавычек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ребята, что Вы парню жизнь усложняете. Блин чтоб вывести ссылку нужно функцию писать. Это просто извращение.

```
$url = $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"];
$title = $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"];
echo "<a href='$url'>$title</a>";
```

Возьми на привычку не пхать в html код длинные имена массивов. Потом сам путаться будешь.

Comment: Да ладно? Видимо усложнил жизнь я ему, да еще как!
Для данной задачи вообще не играет роли ваш метод решения или мой использовать.

Comment: Ну в общем и порешили что Tchort необходимо синтаксис учить

Answer (score 1):

Вы что сами не видите? Разбивайте по строкам. В конце концов напишите себе функцию.

```
<?php
   function takeA($href, $content) {
       return "<a href=\"$href\">$content</a>";
   }

   echo takeA($arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"], $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все варианты, кроме @sensemen, работать будут как надо.

А вообще попахивает битриксом :)

Не мудрено, что битрикс полная лажа, потому что пишут под него те, кто даже синтаксис не знает :)

Answer (score 0):

В двойных кавычках можно выводить так:
    <? echo "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}"; ?>
Для примера.

Answer (score 0):

Только не говорите, что за тегами `<? ... ?>` у вас идет простой html.

В таком случае стоило бы сделать:

```
<a href="<?=$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]?>">
  <?=$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]?>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<? echo "<a href=\"".$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]."\"".$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["SITE_NAME"]["VALUE"]."></a>";?>
```

Comment: Во-первых, свои ответы можно править или писать комментарии.
Во вторых, вы отдаете себе отчет в том, что у вас получится от такой записи?